# event.allTouches()?.allObjects.last

Tags: ios, touchesbegan, ios8.3

now with swift 2.0, IOS 8.3 this code doesn't work anymore.
'Set' does not have a member named 'allObjects'

```
public override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    var touch: UITouch = event.allTouches()?.allObjects.last as UITouch!
}
```

I tried a lot of stuffs but nothing seems to work, any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift 1.2 has introduced a native `Set` type, but unlike `NSSet` it doesn't have the `anyObject` method.  You have a couple of options.  You can use the `first()` method or you can take advantage of the ability to bridge a Swift Set to NSSet -

```
let touch = touches.first() as? UITouch
```

or

```
let touchesSet=touches as NSSet
let touch=touchesSet.anyObject() as? UITouch
```

Comment: thanks your stuff did the job like this : let touch : UITouch = (touches.first as? UITouch)!

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that, too. I'm not sure if this is the actual alternation for the original code these days... I'm sure it isn't. But I've simply changed that code to this:

```
(touches: NSObject, withEvent event: UIEvent)
```

Sorry if that doesn't work for you. It's been working for me perfectly fine.